# Convert int to string to display on lcd, atmel studio c language

Tags: c, avr, atmega, atmel, atmelstudio

i write a program in atmel studio for my avr atmega 32 ic. By keypad enter a  number between 0 to999. I want to display it on lcd.
My problem is: lcd take only char and string.i store the entered number in a int variable. How can i convert it to string or char. 
I writted this function; Y is entered number by keypad that is int:

```
char str;
itoa(y,str,10);
alcd_putc(str);
```

Bu it dosent work. Help me thanks.

Comment: You can use `sprintf()` instead of `itoa()` if it is available.

Comment: Shouldn't str be an array like str[10]?

Comment: Dear achal thanks,  can you explain more?           Sprintf(str,y)????

Comment: Can you write your answer with my variables and cides i write above?

Comment: Sprint(str,”%d”,y);    Lcd_puts(y);   Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`alcd_puts`](http://k-el.com/dochost/eppl_lib_example/group___a_l_c_d_d_r_v.html#ga77b918cdd79bbf19a84856b3a3c71a84) function like following:

```
char str[5]; //< Use a array of char
itoa(y,str,10);
alcd_puts(str);
```

Comment: Thanks dear. But why str[5] not str[8]. What is diffrence?   And i do it before it doesnt work in atmel studio  someone tell me atmel dont find this function as standard function. So told me use sprintf() but it doesnt work too.

Comment: @Aashkanpasha it should be max number of digits in `y` plus an extra for a NULL character. You could use `str[8]` as well, but since you're doing embedded programming might have memory constraints, if few scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. What about this point that atmel dont know this itoa as standard function and i cant use it in atmel. Can you give me a answer by using sprintf???

Comment: @Aashkanpasha `char str[5]; snprintf(str, 5, "%d", y);`

Comment: Thanks dear. It worked. But i find that my problm is another where.  I take numbers by scanning keypad and store them in a array name l[i]. Array have 3 element like {1,2,6} or  one element {1} or two element{5,3}. Lenght of aray is between 1to3 number we can only enter numbers under1000 by keypad . I couldnt make int y=l[0]l[1]l[2] example y=126. Howcan i do it. Then itoa is reached.